# Woocommerce Не меняется символ валюты в шапке

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно изменить знак украинской валюты на  `грн.`.
Использовал следующий код:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
 
function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    
    switch( $currency ) {
        case 'UAH': $currency_symbol = ' грн.'; break; 
    }

    return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Код работает в товарах, но в шапке корзины не меняет. При перезагрузки страницы на мгновение сначала грузится грн, а потом меняется на ₴.

Подскажите, что я не так сделал?

Comment: Я почти уверен, что корзина в шапке сайта выводится через фрагмент, т.е. он закешировался в браузере. Можно проверить в режиме инкогнито или принудительно сбросить все фрагменты

Comment: @noname228 Вы абсолютно правы, в этом и была проблема. Спасибо!

Comment: @noname228 Опубликуйте ответ, чтоб его можно было отметить и вопрос не будет висеть открытым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно очистить кеш браузера. Мне помог перезапуск хрома, а не ctrl+f5. Думаю, если очистить все данные браузера тоже сработает.